# How to see property available values when "string literal type" is used inside Interface in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

**Problem:** As you can see If I declare `gender` with union type of `female | male`, it is throwing the right error as expected (1st image). An also showing the available values on the error (2nd image).

[image]
[image]

However, If I separate gender property as a separate string literal type `Gender` as in the picture below and it also throws the same error (3rd image) but when I hover over `gender` property it does not show me available values but just shows `Gender`. (4th image).

[image]
[image]

**Question:** How can I achieve the same result (showing available values) using string literal types inside Interface? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I will answer my own question:**

If you guys are wondering why this occurs,  it is by design as @pushkin mentioned below, but if you want to see the available values that you can pass, simple you have to press **`CONTROL + SPACE`** to see available values while assigning the value.

Examples:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6638) issue, and the consensus is that this is by design.

> this is actually as designed.... IMO showing more information in the signature hover would only makes things more complicated. Think about a literal with many properties.

Later...

> No there is currently no option to control this.

The issue talks about interfaces, but I presume the same is true for types, which is what my experience has been.

Maybe there is some VSCode extension that can change the hover effect.

Hovering over the actual type declaration however will show this additional information.